# input type="file" multiple передаёт лишь последний файл

Tags: html

У меня такая проблема: Есть форма обратной связи, для отправки на почту, вот кусок от неё, в котором есть input с атрибутом multiple.

```
<form method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data' action="ссылка">
<input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" multiple />
<button type="submit" name="button">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

В input можно загрузить несколько файлов. И когда нажимаю кнопку, на почту отправляется только один файл. В результате выяснил, что в методе POST в момент отправки находится только один, а именно последний файл, хотя вроде бы должен быть массив файлов.
Что делать?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос `var_dump($_FILES['file'])`

Comment: какой вопрос? я программирую на джанго если что.

Comment: Вы вопрос задали, не заметили? Не важно на чем программируете, покажите дебаг массива

Comment: Как вы загружаете «несколько файлов»? Нажимаете несколько раз на кнопку?